# prevent page reload and call a jquery function when submit button is clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, reload

The form tag contents are:-

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>" >
```

The button tag contents are :-

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Submit">
```

The j-query functions are

```
$('#submit_button').click(function ()
            {        
                alert("button clicked");
                buildingVal = $("#building").val();
                levelVal = $("#level").val();
                data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + 'level=' + levelVal.val();
                $.ajax(
                {

                    url: "res.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,     
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
```

The page is getting reloaded, and the data in the textboxes and dropdown menus are disappearing.

but if i have only this code in the jquery:-

```
$('#submit_button').click(function ()
            {        
                alert("button clicked");
 return false;
            });
```

then the page doesn't reload and the values remains intact.

Please could you tell me how am i to prevent the page from reloading?

Also in the ajax call i will be calling a page res.php which will return a table,

What will the code be in the

```
success: function (data) {
                    }
```

please help...

Edit:

I am passing the data into the res.php page with the code

```
data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + 'level=' + levelVal.val();
```

and then pass it into the page using

```
$.ajax(
                {

                    url: "res.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,     
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#npc').html(data);
                    }
                });
```

in the res.php page

how do i extract the two values from the single value that was passed

i have tried using the following code

```
$building = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['building']);
$level = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['level']);
```

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an error in jQuery code:

Error:

```
buildingVal = $("#building").val();
levelVal = $("#level").val();
data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + 'level=' + levelVal.val();
```

Solution:

```
buildingVal = $("#building");
levelVal = $("#level");
data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + '&level=' + levelVal.val();
```

Complete code js:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function () {        

   var 
       buildingVal = $("#building"),
       levelVal = $("#level"),
       data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + '&level=' + levelVal.val();


   $.ajax({
      'url': 'res.php', 
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': data,     
      'success': function (data) {
      }
   });

   return false;

});
```

**Edit**

If your ever going to use this form to send data by ajax, the best way is to cancel the event "submit" the form:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ;?>" >
...
</form>
```

JS:

```
$('#myform').bind('submit', function(event) {

     return false;
});

$('#submit_button').bind('click', function () {        

   var 
       buildingVal = $("#building"),
       levelVal = $("#level"),
       data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + 'level=' + levelVal.val();


   $.ajax({
      'url': 'res.php', 
      'type': 'POST',
      'data': data,     
      'success': function (data) {
      }
   });

});
```

Comment: That did help me solve my first part of the question. But the second part is still confusing me..
What do i write in the success : function to print the table that i am echoing from the res.php page.

Comment: @debal I do not know that returns "res.php", but if returns a html you should replace your html, for example with `$ (...). html (data)`. if you are doing an ajax call you have to replace the data to update.

Comment: could you help me with one other thing please.. i have mentioned it in the edit of the original question...

Comment: @debal ok, but this is another question, can you create another question with this, pass me the link in a comment

Comment: the link to my new question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12215960/acquire-parameters-in-a-php-page-which-is-called-by-a-ajax-function

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to not use a `submit` button in the first place.

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" value="Submit">


$('#myButton').on('click', function(){
   //do ajax
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior in your click event:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function (event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("button clicked");
    return false; // Not truly necerssary
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 0):

So in order for the submit button to not submit your page with its default behavior do the following:

```
$('#submit_button').click(function (event) {        
                event.preventDefault();
                buildingVal = $("#building").val();
                levelVal = $("#level").val();
                data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + 'level=' + levelVal.val();
                $.ajax(
                {

                    url: "res.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: data,     
                    success: function (data) {
                    }
                });                
});
```