# acquire parameters in a php page which is called by a ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, parameter-passing

i am calling a php page res.php using jquery and ajax. The code is:-

```
$('#submit_button').click(function () {        
    buildingVal = $("#building");
    levelVal = $("#level");
    data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + 'level=' + levelVal.val();
    $.ajax( {

        url: "res.php", 
        type: "POST",
        data: data,     
        success: function (data) {
            $('#npc').html(data);
        }
    });​
});
```

the res.php page codes are:-

```
<?php
//connect to the database
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","12345") or die("error ".mysql_error());

//connect to the travian table
mysql_select_db("trav",$con) or die("error ".mysql_error());

$building = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['building']);
$level = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['level']);


$query = "select * from ";
$query = $query . $building;
$query = $query . "where lvl=" . $level;
$query = $query . ";";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error in Child Table!');

$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

echo '<table><tr><td>Lumber=$data["lumber"]</td><td>Clay=$data["clay"]</td><td>Iron=$data["iron"]</td><td>Crop=$data["crop"]</td>';

?>
```

I am receiving the error

```
Notice: Undefined index: building in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\res.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: level in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\res.php on line 9
Error in Child Table!
```

How am i to extract both the parameters that were sent to the page and use them in the sql query to retrieve the data from the table in the database.
Please could you help me..

Comment: In your ajax function try : `data: {building: buildingVal.val(), level: levelVal.val()},`or at least split the querystring you're using whith an ampersand. and you're confusing post with get.

Comment: if you are doing a post the format should be like this data = {building: buildingVal.val() + level: levelVal.val();}

Comment: @AshirvadSingh - both objects and strings are valid as data, and the former is often times more readable.

Comment: Why don't you submit a form with those values in its fields (they can be hidden)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are sending $_POST values through AJAX and trying to assign variables from $_GET on your res.php page. Change either AJAX function to `type: "GET"`, or

```
$building = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['building']);
$level = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['level']);
```

on res.php

also you're not sending the 'level' variable properly, you're missing an '&'

```
data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + '&level=' + levelVal.val();
```

Comment: I changed the code to $_POST the first part of the error seems to have been solved, but the second part is still present.

`Notice: Undefined index: level in C:\xampp\htdocs\debal\res.php on line 9
Error in Child Table!`

It seems that the second parameter is not being retrieved. How am i to retrieve both the parameters.

Comment: add '&' before 'level' like this: data = 'building=' + buildingVal.val() + '&level=' + levelVal.val();

Comment: I'm not sure what error you get but try to change the 'where' line to: $query = $query . " where lvl=" . $level; I think you're missing a white space character before the 'where'