# Is there a rubygem to prevent a page from reloading on a controller call? If not where do I put javascript/jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a table where each row has a select_tag and a submit_tag.  I'd like to call this without reloading the page.  I have the full functionality in place but the page has to reload.

If there's no gem, let's say I try something like this:  [prevent page reload and call a jquery function when submit button is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214624/prevent-page-reload-and-call-a-jquery-function-when-submit-button-is-clicked).  Where do I put the jquery code?

Comment: Sorry, are you familiar with AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the `:remote` option in your `form_for` call. Check out the [Unobtrusive JavaScript documentation under form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for-label-Unobtrusive+JavaScript). This will add a `data-remote="true"` attribute to your form, which Rails's [Unobtrusive scripting adapter for jQuery](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) uses to automatically convert the form to an Ajax call.

You can then provide the jQuery code you want to execute on a successful create or update into `app/views/posts/create.js.erb` or `app/views/posts/update.js.erb`

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way you could just add some gem or script in order to make your requests in table not to reload the page. With AJAX or PJAX you may make a request to server, retrieve data, and re-render (a cell, column, table, whatever).

Helpful links:
PJAX -- http://railscasts.com/episodes/294-playing-with-pjax;
AJAX -- http://bernatfarrero.com/jquery-and-rails-3-mini-tutorial/